# Problem about grundy value of grundy's game

Tags: algorithm, math, game-theory

I was working on a Grundy's game. The rules of this game are

For each pile, you have to split into unequal piles.
This link tells you more about the grundy game.
https://oeis.org/A002188

This is the link for n=1.....10000 grundy values
https://oeis.org/A002188/b002188.txt

the max value of n for which grundy value is 0 is 1222. Why ? can anyone explain?
I know about the Sprague-Grundy theorem.
This problem can be solved recursively using this theorem. But why the max value is 1222.
Is there any reason for having 0 for smaller values and not for larger n.

Comment: For N > 1222 it is always possible to reach a configuration with value 0, so the mex has to be > 0. But this is only conjectured not proven.

Comment: In other words, for N > 1222 it is conjectured that the pile can always be split into two piles for which both have the same value (so their xor is 0).

Comment: okay thanks for reply